# Probability of sequence match

Tags: probability, statistics

I have 2 sequences of numbers as follows with numbers ranging from 1-4:
sequence 1: 2 2 3 1 4 4 1 1 4 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 3
sequence 2: 4 2 2 1 1 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 2 3 2 4 4 2 4 1 4 2 1 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 3 2

I want to find the probability that at least 2 segments of 3 numbers each match in the 2 sequences.

Probability of 2 numbers appearing together is as follows:
For example, the first 2 numbers that appear together are 2 and 4. So, P(2, 4) = n(2, 4)/length(sequence)  =  1/37.

My question is for same numbers in the 2 sequences. For ex. (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4).

A 'segment of 3 numbers' means 3 pairs (one from the first sequence and one from the second sequences) of numbers adjacent to each other. For example:
sequence 1: **1 3 2** 3 2
sequence 2: **1 3 2** 1 3
The segment in bold forms one such segment.

How can I find this probability?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can we assume that the numbers are generated by a 4 sided fair cube ?

Comment: @Peter The probability of any number in the sequence is the total number of times that number appears divided by the length of the sequence. For example, P(1,1)=6/37.
Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you are just looking at those sequences then you can count the number of times "at least 2 segments of 3 numbers each match in the 2 sequences".  It is not a probability

Comment: @Henry I think OP means that one is supposed to estimate the pmf's that generated the sequences by the empirical distributions and then calculate the probability.